# Remove duplicates in each individual column from a text file

Tags: sorting, awk, uniq

I have a text file of 7 tab-delimited columns. Each column has a different number of lines with values that could be duplicated. I want to remove the duplicates so that each column has only unique values for that specific column. As an example:

Input

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7
111 111 222 333 111 222 777 
222 111 333 333 222 333 666
222 111 444 111 333 555 555
333 444 555 222 444 666 444
444 666 555 777 555 666 333
444 777 777 555 666 888 333
777 888 999 666 888                 
999
```

Output

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7
111 111 222 333 111 222 777
222 444 333 111 222 333 666
333 666 444 222 333 555 555
444 777 555 777 444 666 444
777 888 777 555 555 888 333
999     999 666 666 
                888
```

I figure I would need to use awk to print each column and use sort -u separately, and then paste those outputs together. So, is there a way to make a loop that for i number of columns in a text file, would print each column | sort - u, and then paste it all together?

Thanks in advance,
Carlos

Comment: Transpose, then make unique number in lines, then transpose again.

Comment: `paste <(awk '!seen[$1]++ && $0=$1' file) <(awk '!seen[$2]++ && $0=$2' file) <(awk '!seen[$3]++ && $0=$3' file) <(awk '!seen[$4]++ && $0=$4' file) <(awk '!seen[$5]++ && $0=$5' file) <(awk '!seen[$6]++ && $0=$6' file) <(awk '!seen[$7]++ && $0=$7' file)` ;-)

Comment: Thank you @Cyrus, that works for this specific file. However, I'm going to do this in the future with files that have a random number of columns. Is there a way to do something like: for i columns do paste <(awk '!seen[$i]++ && $0=$i file
?

Comment: @Carlos Cyrus was kidding, note the smiley emoji at the end of their comment.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, I already saw the catastrophe coming that it wouldn't stay at 7 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=NF; colNr++) {
        val = $colNr
        if ( !seen[colNr,val]++ ) {
            rowNr = ++colRowNrs[colNr]
            vals[rowNr,colNr] = val
            numRows = (rowNr > numRows ? rowNr : numRows)
        }
    }
    numCols = (NF > numCols ? NF : numCols)
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            val = vals[rowNr,colNr]
            printf "%s%s", val, (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
C1      C2      C3      C4      C5      C6      C7
111     111     222     333     111     222     777
222     444     333     111     222     333     666
333     666     444     222     333     555     555
444     777     555     777     444     666     444
777     888     777     555     555     888     333
999             999     666     666
                                888
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions

- an (`awk`) array of the entire output result will fit in memory
- variable number of columns and rows

One idea consists of a (sparse) 2-dimensional array of values, where the array structure would look like:

```
values[<column#>][<row#>]=<unique_cell_value>
```

One idea using a single `awk` invocation that *a)* requires a single pass through the input file and *b)* does not require any transposing/pasting (in case anyone takes Cyrus' comment/suggestion seriously):

```
awk '
BEGIN  { FS=OFS="\t" }
       { maxNF = (NF > maxNF ? NF : maxNF)            # keep track of max number of columns
         for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
             if ( $i == "" )                          # ignore empty cell
                continue
             for (j=1; j<=ndx[i]; j++) {              # loop through values already seen for this column
                 if ( $i == vals[i][j] ) {            # and if already seen then
                    $i = ""                           # clear the current cell and
                    break                             # break out of this for/testing loop
                 }
             }
             if ( $i != "" ) {                        # if we got this var and the cell is not empty then 
                vals[i][++ndx[i]] = $i                # store the new value in our array
             }
         }
       }
END    { for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) {                      # loop through all possible rows
             pfx = ""
             for (i=1; i<=maxNF; i++) {               # loop through all possible columns
                 printf "%s%s", pfx, vals[i][j]       # non-existent array entries default to ""
                 pfx = OFS
             }
             printf "\n"
         }
       }
' input_file
```

**NOTE:** The array of arrays structure (`arr[i][j]`) requires `GNU awk` otherwise we could convert to a pseudo dual index array structure of `arr[i,j]`

This generates:

```
C1      C2      C3      C4      C5      C6      C7
111     111     222     333     111     222     777
222     444     333     111     222     333     666
333     666     444     222     333     555     555
444     777     555     777     444     666     444
777     888     777     555     555     888     333
999             999     666     666
                                888
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl` instead for its support of true multidimensional arrays:

```sh
perl -lane '
    for my $n (0..$#F) {
      if (!exists ${$vals[$n]}{$F[$n]}) {
        push @{$cols[$n]}, $F[$n];
        ${$vals[$n]}{$F[$n]} = 1;
      }
    }
    END {
      for (1..$.) {
        my @row;
        for my $n (0..$#cols) {
          push @row, shift @{$cols[$n]};
        }
        print join("\t", @row);
     }
}' input.txt
```